# Debug memory leak using FastMM4

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

Using FastMM4 and on application exit I am informed of a leak of a single critical section:

```
21 - 36 bytes: TCriticalSection x 1
```

All declared TCriticalSection objects have been carefully checked and a breakpoint set on the corresponding `critObj.Free();` line. The "lockCount" parameter is -1 in each case. Everything appears in order.

Is it possible to determine to whom this pesky critical section belongs (or can FastMM4 help)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine to whom this pesky critical section belongs (or can FastMM4 help)?

Configure FastMM4 to be able to show you a stack trace for the allocation of the leaked object. On process shutdown a log file is written containing detailed reports on the leaks, including the stack trace that I describe.

Once that has revealed where the object is created, it is typically straightforward to work out why it was not destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, good tip. I've carefully reviewed the log file created by FastMM4 and the only bit of information I was able to glean is that the TCriticalSection was allocated by the main thread, specifically the thread ID returned by a call to GetCurrentThreadId() in the main form. The rest of the information was a stack trace (with 6-digit hex addresses), machine code and a memory dump.

Comment: You need to use the full FastMM with full debug mode, using the fastmm debug dll. Search through the FastMM4Options.inc file for references to stack traces, and make sure you enable the options that ensure stack traces are produced.

Comment: Thanks, AFAICS those options are set: (1) {$define FullDebugMode} (2) {$define RawStackTraces} (3) used Process Explorer to confirm FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll is loaded by my process.

Comment: I see stack traces here. Without full knowledge of all your compilation options, it's hard to know what's missing.

Comment: UPDATE: The TCriticalSection deliberately leaked produces only a minor difference in the FastMM4 log. (1) The allocation number is much higher (4071 compared with 489). (2) The stack trace consists of 11 entries of 6-digit return addresses. The leaked object I'm tracking has 10 entries of 6-digits and then the 11th entry is "7C90DCBA [ZwSetInformationThread]". I cannot make sense of the rest of the log, but it appears to be machine code. The deliberately leaked object has address 7FE945E0 and the object I'm tracking has address 7FF47770. Is that meaningful?

Comment: OK. Are you building a full map file? Do you use software like madexcept, eurekalog or jcldebug? I think fastmm will piggyback them for stack trace symbols. But without that I believe a full map file will suffice, IIRC.

Comment: My map file was set to "Off"! I changed that to "Detailed" and I am now getting a more interesting stack trace in the FastMM4 log! Could you add a note about configuring the map file and I can accept the answer. Does the map file affect the EXE speed/size? Now I just need to decipher the stack trace!

Comment: No, the map file is an external file that is not used by the executable. I don't want to change my answer to speak to your specific configuration, which in any case is not presented in the question. There are many different reasons why a stack traced could not be decoded. I don't really want to write a full tutorial on that here since I think the question was more general, and I think I answered it. If you disagree, if you don't think this has been helpful and has not answered the question you asked, don't vote, don't accept. Entirely up to you.